# reading python indentations in files within a project

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, indentation, lexical-analysis

In the Python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation) are explained how indentations are computed during coding with Python. [Here](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/8674/how-indentation-is-parsed) is another explanation, plus this:

For example:

```
if foo:
   if bar:
       x = 42
else:
    print foo
```

is analyzed as:

```
<if> <foo> <:>                    [0]
<INDENT> <if> <bar> <:>           [0, 4]
<INDENT> <x> <=> <42>             [0, 4, 8]
<DEDENT> <DEDENT> <else> <:>      [0]
<INDENT> <print> <foo>            [0, 2]
<DEDENT>
```

Now, I am wondering if these data about the indentation spaces, within `[]` brackets, are saved somewhere, of if I can read them somehow for each file in a python project.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: They are not saved, so you would have to recompute them.

Comment: @rici , Thank you! Do you know what is the best way (what tool I can use) to recompute them?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html